# How to open React.js app on mobile using Ip

Tags: reactjs, shared

I'm trying to share my React app on my mobile. I'm connected to both devices on the same wifi and I use the IP address and then the host port xxx.xxx.xx:3000/ .the phone can not search the site something details are missing?

Comment: Have tried the steps in official doc https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#method-2-connect-via-wi-fi

Answer (score 1):

You must specify host IP there, currently your app is serverd only for localhost, if you are using webpack try to run `npm start --host 0.0.0.0`

Comment: How to run this command in next.js? I tried yarn dev --host xxx.xxx.xxx Did not work

Comment: For nextjs you can change host in `package.json` in dev script by simply adding `-H 192.168.1.1` or so, it will be something like: `"dev": "next dev -H 192.168.1.1"` you can try your IP or zeros but i think that nextjs use zeros as default.... but you can try, if it dosnt help, problem can be on firewall or something else.

Comment: Did this actually work for anyone? I have been trying this and all I get is a blank screen.